# Apache CSV Commons: IOException: (line 5) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Tags: java, apache-commons

Apache CSV Commons library interrupted with exception:

```
IOException: (line 5) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
```

It tries to read following .csv file:

```
"id", "category_id", "brand_id", "catalog_number"
"6427146", "4045", "764\"13", "A26-30-01"
"6425052", "4058", "764\"13", "P9B02VN"
"6424406", "4054", "764\"13", "A40-30-10-80"
"6152302", "4046", "764\"13", "1.75\\" center distance"
"6152301", "4046", "764\"13", "ZL110"
"6152300", "4046", "764\"13", "ZAF460-70"
"6152299", "4046", "764\"13", "ZA75-84"
"6152298", "4046", "764\"13", "ZA75-80"
"6152297", "4046", "764\"13", "ZA75-55-1SBN153510R5506"
```

Library cannot read line #5.

Code:

```
@Test
public void testReadCsvFile() throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new FileReader("products-with-escaped-escape-symbol.csv");

    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
            .withHeader(HEADERS)
            .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
            .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
            .withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()
            .withEscape('\\')
            .parse(reader);

    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
        String brandId = record.get("brand_id");
        assertThat(brandId, is("764\"13"));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to adjust Apache CSV Commons library to read a .csv file with such structure?

Comment: You're using `withEscape('\\')`.  Can you not just remove that switch and then format your returned value accordingly?

Comment: @Reilas I cannot change format of generated .csv file. It generated by 3rd party.

Comment: I'm suggesting to remove the `withEscape('\\')` builder call you have.  Then, use `record.get("brand_id").replace("\\", "")`.

Comment: You have been given an invalid CSV file.  CSVFormat will never be able to parse it.  Fixing it programmatically will likely require parsing the entire line yourself.

Comment: @VGR It's fine that CSVFormat won't parse such line but possibly there is a way to edit/change the line before it will be parsed by CSVFormat. I guess, Reilas gave a nice idea.

Comment: You need `.withEscape('\\')` if you’re going to use CSVFormat at all.  That method is the only reason `"764\"13"` is parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is let the source of this data know that they have povided you with invalid input.  They are supposed to send a CSV file and they did failed to do that.  This input is not a CSV file, it merely somewhat resembles a CSV file.

If that option is not available, you can create your own Reader which filters each line before passing it to the CSVParser:

```
List<CSVRecord> records;

CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
        .withHeader(HEADERS)
        .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
        .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
        .withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()
        .withEscape('\\');

try (PipedReader reader = new PipedReader();
     PipedWriter writer = new PipedWriter(reader)) {

    Runnable filterTask = () -> {
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = Files.newBufferedReader(
                Path.of("products-with-escaped-escape-symbol.csv"));
             PipedWriter filteredWriter = writer) {

            String line;
            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.replaceAll(
                    "^(" +
                    "(?:\\s*\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"\\s*,)*" +
                    "\\s*\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\[^\\\\])*" +
                    ")" +
                    "\\\\\\\\\"($|\\s*[^,])", "$1\\\\\"$2");
                filteredWriter.write(line);
                filteredWriter.write('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    };

    CompletableFuture<?> filter = CompletableFuture.runAsync(filterTask);

    try (CSVParser parser = format.parse(reader)) {
        records = parser.getRecords();
        filter.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        if (cause instanceof RuntimeException re) {
            throw re;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(cause);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
}
```

This is not a completely reliable solution.  If a comma followed `\\"` and that comma was intended to be part of the value, rather than a value separator, writing code to recognize that case would be a lot more complicated.